# Wordpress Category to Menu

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I have created several categories with sub-categories, I want to display the category in a menu so I created the menu inside appearance-->Menus, now what I want to be displaying is the created categories(with the respective sub-categories) in the menu. I went to the categoryName, when I selected the Category1 with the hope of getting all the sub-categories automatically, I only get the Category1 back, when I clicked **view all-->select all-->add to menu** unfortunately it shows all the categories with the sub-category at **the same level**. Please how can WordPress newbie, that have close to zero knowledge of php programming achieve this task? Or is there any plugin for that? Oh I forgot to mention that the only option I'm seeing is to start dragging(over 200 categories and still counting) and arranging in the menu. Please is there any other way to hasten my task?

Answer (score 0):

Im the menu, you can drag and drop to arrange menus. Drag a menu to the right a bit to make it a sub menu under a certain menu

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that the only option I'm seeing is to start dragging(over 200 categories) and arranging in the menu. Please is there any other way to hasten my task?